# How to draw a LaTeX diagram to represent a cascade connection of two blocks?

Tags: floats, diagrams

As I am new to drawing diagrams using LaTeX, I request help from the LaTeX experts here in answering this question : How to draw a  LaTeX diagram to represent a cascade connection of two blocks as in the enclosed figure?

Thanks for your great help !

[image]

Comment: With TikZ you have five nodes (2 with [draw] and 3 with [midway,above]) and 3 arrows [-latex]. Each node has (east) and (west) anchor points.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this picture with `TikZ`. For a beginner, here is my suggestion: Place four nodes called `(A)`, `(B)`, `(C)` and `(D)` at coordinates along the x-axis. The middle nodes need `[draw]` for the rectangle, but the outer nodes are invisible. The middle nodes also have text inside. `minimum width` keeps the nodes the same size (even the invisible ones).

Then draw arrows (`latex` is the arrow type) between the nodes and label each arrow (above) with *another* node.

Since I placed the nodes too close together, I used `xscale` to stretch the picture horizontally. This does not stretch the text, arrowheads or node shapes, only the placement of the nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2.5]
\node[minimum width=1cm](A) at (0,0){};
\node[minimum width=1cm, draw](B) at (1,0){$\scriptstyle G_1(s)$};
\node[minimum width=1cm, draw](C) at (2,0){$\scriptstyle G_2(s)$};
\node[minimum width=1cm](D) at (3,0){};
\draw[thick, -latex] (A) to node[above]{$\mathrm{U}(s)$} (B);
\draw[thick, -latex] (B) to node[above]{$\mathrm{V}(s)$} (C);
\draw[thick, -latex] (C) to node[above]{$\mathrm{Y}(s)$} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

As being simple diagram, I'm not consider about `Tikz` and `PsTricks`, etc. and tried with tabular format only, and the codes are:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c}
$\mathop{\hbox to 2pc{\rightarrowfill}}\limits^{U(S)}$
&\fbox{$G_1(s)$} &$\mathop{\hbox to
2pc{\rightarrowfill}}\limits^{V(S)}$ &\fbox{$G_2(s)$} &$\mathop{\hbox to 2pc{\rightarrowfill}}\limits^{Y(S)}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. If you find time, kindly add a new answer on how to draw the same using Tikz; It may be useful for many new learners.. - Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I propose this short code with `pstricks`:

```
    \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-node}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{psmatrix}
    \pnode(0, 0.5ex){A} & \rnode{B}{\framebox{$G_1(s)$}} & \rnode{C}{\framebox{$G_2(s)$}} &\pnode(0,0.5ex){D}
    \psset{arrowinset=0.1, arrows=->, labelsep=1pt}
    \ncline{A}{B}\naput{U(s)} \ncline{B}{C}\naput{V(s)} \ncline{C}{D}\naput{Y(s)}
    \end{psmatrix}

    \end{document}
```

[image]